# SW ZFS vs. HW RAID controller

Tags: raid, freebsd, software-raid, hardware-raid

I run a FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE webserver, and I have 2 sata HDD on a HW RAID1 controller, but when I installed the OS, it won't do it on a ZFS filesystem (for mirroring as I intended to) but I was forced to install it on UFS filesystem.

How? Why? Someone explain to me: HW RAID exclude ZFS RAID ?

How can I Install a *BSD distro on a HW RAID controller (I'm not allowed to open the case of server) and make with ZFS filesystem mirror to 2xsata HDD's.

Comment: I installed FreeBSD last in version 9 but back then there was no simple way to install FreeBSD on a ZFS root. Appart from that ZFS works best if it knows most about the Hardware. Therefore it is advised to use ZFS on the HDDs directly instead through a raid.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say what happened during your install without more info which at this point is probably not available.

In theory, even if your HW RAID was enabled and therefore the OS only saw 1 physical disk, you should still be able to put ZFS on that, though it would be a bad idea. It's always better to disable the hardware RAID when using ZFS. You should be able to configure the HW RAID into JBOD mode via the BIOS, without opening the case.

I know the 10.1 installer supports ZFS as root filesystem and I believe it should support setting up the drivers in a mirrored config, though it's been a while, so I'd have to run through it to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you have HW RAID enabled in mode 0 or 1 and the controller is presenting one unified disk to FreeBSD. You either have to configure your controller for JBOD or if that's not supported then set up a RAID 0 array for each disk in your system.